Centralize and reuse CASE WHEN logic in SQL Server views
I have a pretty long CASE WHEN expression in a view which creates two dynamic columns given some logic.
However, now I need to add this same logic to another view and create the dynamic columns there. I could copy paste the same logic, but then any changes would have to be made in both places.
Is there an optimal way to centralize this logic and/or make it a function that the CREATE VIEW statements can reference?
WITH_REPORTING_PIVOTS AS (
    SELECT 
        I.*,
        CASE
            WHEN I.Code = 'Condition' THEN ISNULL(Type1, Type2)
            WHEN Tag1 = 'Condition' THEN ISNULL(Tag2, Tag3) 
            WHEN I.Detail IS NOT NULL THEN 
                CONCAT(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN 
                            ISNULL(Code, Code2) IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN 
                            CONCAT(
                                ISNULL(Code, Code2),
                                ' '
                            )
                        ELSE ''
                    END,
                    Detail
                )
            WHEN I.Type1 = 'Condition' THEN 
                CONCAT(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN I.Code = 'Condition' THEN 'Value'
                            ELSE Code
                        END,
                        ' ', I.Description, 
                        ' ', I.Type1
                    )
            ELSE I.Tag1
        END AS DyanmicColumn1,
        CASE 
            WHEN 
                Tag1 = 'Condition' 
                THEN REPLACE(I.Tag4, 'string', '')
            WHEN I.Code = 'Condition' THEN SubType
            WHEN I.Detail IS NOT NULL THEN 
                CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(SubTag, SubTag2) IS NOT NULL THEN
                        CASE 
                            WHEN ISNULL(SubTag, SubTag2) = 'N/A' THEN NULL
                            ELSE ISNULL(SubTag, SubTag2)
                        END
                END
            ELSE Tag2
        END AS DyanmicColumn2


The issue that each row value of the DynamicColumns depends on the existing column values in each view. So the values have to be evaluated rather than just looked-up

You can create a inline Table-valued-function that returns these case whens based on some input columns, but it will still be a hassle updating it for new conditions, since you probably need to add more parameters etc. Perhaps it's worth taking closer look on the general design, these kind of case whens can be a sign of bad design
